# Fixed header image that is overlayed by a semi-transparent image when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, scroll, header, overlay

I'm trying create an effect on a header image that will progressively blur and fade that image on scrolling down. I've tried to search online for a solution but I don't even know what to call it.  I have found an example very close to what i'd like to achieve but I don't quite understand how they've done it either. My experiments have been a total flop and I was wondering if anyone could either point me in the right direction or at least let me know what something like this might be called so that I can search for a solution.  Thanks for your time.

The example site is https://www.intertel.co.za/password-grabber

(You'll notice how the background image is almost black by the time the page content reaches the top of the screen - that's what I want)

I've included a snippet here so you can see my dismal attempt

```css
.header-container {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100vw;
height:25vh;
overflow:hidden;
}

.header-image {
background-image:url(header-image.jpg);
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0 0;
background-attachment:fixed;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:1;
}

.header-overlay {
background-image:url(header-overlay.png);
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0 0;
position:fixed;
top:100%;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-bottom:-25vw;
z-index:2;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
 <div class="header-image"></div>
 <div class="header-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a solution in pure CSS but you should try using Javascript to create a function that modifies your `div` style when scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [CSS Filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/). With these, you can blur images, add/remove contrast and a lot more.

The link you have provided makes use of a blurred image that has been created beforehand. When you're at the top of the page it has an `opacity` of 0, which goes up to a max of 1 when you're scrolling down.

Their approach **is** less resource heavy, but not the ideal way, if you ask me. If you use CSS Filters, you will be able to give the same effect to every image you want without having to create a blurred out copy every time you want to use a new banner image.

The way you achieve the effect is fairly easy with JavaScript. I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtzfmgju/) to demonstrate the effect. Of course you can do a lot more with this piece of code, like shifting the hue, removing contrast, etc.

Hope this helps